# Strange behavior with candle and bin

Tags: forces, air

In a corner of a room there is a window where there use to be wax and oil candles burning. Just below the candles, there is a bin. There is a lot of soot on the wall and the ceiling, but not over the bin. On the ceiling, there is a white mark exactly the same shape and size of the bin and soot all around it.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain why to me. Thank you.

Edit:

It is in living room/kitchen

The bin is used a lot with food(can potentially generate heat from decomposition?)

I checked with the neighbor, he doesn't have anything in this place.

After few months I change the place of the bin 30 cm aside and I start to notice the same thing.

[image]

Comment: there is not enough information for this to be a question to be answered on this site

Comment: Ooooo! good one! -NN

Comment: @annav , so you are saying it is paranormal?

Comment: Photographs would help us understand the situation.

Comment: @Markh , I added a sketch of the scene

Comment: Probably because the hot air rising from the flame carries the soot upwards and deposits it where the air hits the ceiling. The clean spot in the middle is because there is a stagnation point there.

Comment: @Jacko  the figure is not enough. Are you sure that it is not the shape of  a trap door to the floor above? What heated the room, is this room still used? why don't you watch the path of the smoke of the candles etc etc

Comment: thanks for the help, I added some informations, please let me know if something else can help.

Comment: Perhaps use smoke to investigate the air currents in the room?

Comment: It seems that it comes from the bin, but the question is how it is possible to have net clean spot on the ceiling, which physical phenomenon can explain that.